# Infopath form submission error

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-data-connections, forms-library

I recently moved a section of an on Premise Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online.

The main function of this section is for expense submissions, for this there is a library with a default form for employee expenses created via Infopath.

The form works and calculates fine, however upon submitting the form the following error is given. I have tried editing permissions for the submitting user to include edit and full control, but neither give any better results.

Any idea what the issue might be?

[image: Infopath Error]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update the submit button and ensure the SharePoint address is correct/updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check User whose is submitting the form has contribute permission to a library (form library)/list, verify that the URL is correct and fill in all required fields.